# Отсечь цифры до десятых и округлить

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
число с большим количеством символов после запятой.
Необходимо отсечь (не округлять, хотя в крайнем случае и это допускаю) до десятых.  После этого округлить следующим образом: все что до 0,5, то в меньшую сторону (например 1,3 -> 1 или 4,4 -> 4),
а если 0,5-0,9, то округлять до 0,5 (например 3,5 -> 3,5, 3,8 -> 3,5).
функции floor, ceil, round насколько я понимаю не подходят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$out = floor(2*round($in,1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN))/2
```

Comment: про третий параметр то я и забыл

Comment: спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 3):

```
$out = round($in, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
if($out>$in) $out -= 0.5;
```

Comment: спасибо, вы первым откликнулись, и все же второй вариант изначально мне показался более изящным.